# What is the purpose of ln command in UNIX

Tags: unix

What is the purpose of **ln** command? What is the difference between a **softlink** and a **hardlink**?

Will softlinks/hardlinks help if the original files are deleted?

Comment: Here's the manpage for reference: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ln. softlinks can be deleted without deleting the original target, but if the target is removed, the softlink will point to nothing. Never used hardlinks, so I can't say for sure. BTW keep in mind that just about every Unix command can be found on Google. My advice is to try Googling before posting here to avoid massive downvotes for lack of research effort. Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253, you have always used hardlinks.  Every path is a hardlink.   When you type `touch /tmp/foo`, you create a file and a hard link to that file with the path `/tmp/foo`.  Even paths that are symbolic links are hard links to a symbolic link.  If you type `ln -s /tmp/foo /tmp/bar`, then a symbolic link to `/tmp/foo` is created, and `/tmp/bar` is a hard link to that symbolic link.  Then `ln /tmp/bar /tmp/baz` creates a second hard link to the symbolic link.  Use `ls -i` to see the files that each link references.  Paths are not files; paths are hard links.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, you just blew my mind. I guess I have some reading to do. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ln is a command to generate links. Links are like file alias.

A soft link is when you have a path to the file, so the file might exist or not, and can link files even if they are in different partitions.

Hard links are links to nodes that point to the same contents, so if you delete the original file the content will still exist.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to stack overflow however I think that your answer still needs a little work. Your description of hard links isn't correct as it stands.

Answer (score 3):

Google is your friend. Check out the Wikipedia [ln (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_%28Unix%29) entry which was the top search result when searching for "ln".

From the Wiki article:

> There are two types of links, both of which are created by ln:
>
> - **symbolic links**, which refer to a symbolic path indicating the abstract location of another file, and
> - **hard links**, which refer to the specific location of physical data.
>
> These links behave differently when the source of the link (what is being linked to) is moved or removed. Symbolic links are not updated (they merely contain a string which is the pathname of its target); hard links always refer to the source, even if moved or removed.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of *ln* is to create links. The use cases of links contain eg.

- version control
  you can have multiple installations of libraries, programs, etc. and "point" to the current one
- shortcuts
  as in windows desktop
- creating collections without copying data

These are typically "pointers", i.e. softlinks.
The difference of hardlink and softlink is that when a hardlinked copy of the original file is deleted the file still exists. The feature is implemented by counting references to each file. One has to then delete all references i.e. hardlinks or the original file.

Answer (score 1):

To make links between files we need to use **ln** command. A symbolic link (also known as a soft link or symlink) consists of a special type of file that serves as a reference to another file or directory. Unix/Linux like operating systems often uses symbolic links. **If you create link then your original file will not deleted.**

There are two types of links.

1. **Softlink** : Refer to a symbolic path indicating the abstract location of another file
2. **hard links** : Refer to the specific location of physical data.

Some Reference

http://www.unixtutorial.org/commands/ln/

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ln.1.html